# Erlang, Is it necessary to close the file here?

Tags: erlang

When using `file:read_file(x)` is it necessary to close the returned file?

```
{ok, File} = file:read_file("maillog.sample"), 
file:close(File),
```

Comment: `File` contains the contents of the file...

Comment: For the corresponding question when using `file:open/2`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28066839/113848).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not a file, but the contents of the file that is returned.
Thus, no file to close.
Try changing the variable name to Data or similar as in the code below:

```
{ok, Data} = file:read_file("maillog.sample"),
```

Data will then have the contents of the file "maillog.sample".
The function file:read_file/1 will open, read and close the file for you, all in one go.

Comment: Wow im dumb, since the return tuple is similar to output of file:open(..) I just assumed it was giving back a device. 
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

No it is not necessary to close the files for `file:read_file`, and `file:consult`.

How would you close it anyway, if you don't even have the file descriptor at hand?