# Will the file get automatically closed, when opening process terminates

Tags: erlang

I have a process, which opens the file by using file:open. Will this file get automatically closed, when my process will terminate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. From the documentation of [file:open/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2):

> Returns:
>
> ```
> {ok, IoDevice}
> ```
>
> The file has been opened in the requested mode. `IoDevice` is a reference to the file.

[...]

> `IoDevice` is really the pid of the process which handles the file. This process is linked to the process which originally opened the file. If any process to which the `IoDevice` is linked terminates, the file will be closed and the process itself will be terminated.